# Why is the light in my render so bright?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, camera, lighting

I have been trying to render an image for the last half hour. I have made sure that the light was set to 1.000, but I can see nothing in my render.

[image]

And no matter how low the light setting is, it does not go away. Why is this?

Comment: Switch the shader workspace to the world shader and see what the background strength is set to

Comment: But how do I do that? I am still a bit of a beginner. =)

Answer (score 0):

In the *Shading Tab*'s Shader Editor you can click this button

[image]

to switch from Object shader data to the World shader.  My suspicion is that you've changed it from the default, which looks like this:

[image]

Default value for that color is .051, but in any case you should be able to adjust to your liking from there.

If that isn't it, check the *Outliner* for hidden objects.

There are two hide buttons, one for the viewport and one for renders.

[image]

Comment: i have checked the shading tab editor and the outliner and it is all fine.